# Where can I find base file needed for Euro Truck Simulator 2 mods?

Tags: mods, euro-truck-simulator-2

I have tried everything to get mods on Euro Truck Simulator 2 but it says I need a base file. I have looked everywhere but can't find it. Do I have to download it or should it already be there on the system when I downloaded the game onto my computer?

Comment: Does this base file have a specific name?

Comment: no it just come up that I need a base scs file and I don't know where it is supposed to be I have looked every where but carnt find it.

Answer (score 2):

It should be in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Euro Truck Simulator 2\base.scs** (when you have default installation folder in Windows 7). Maybe you have hidden that file. Here is nice tutorial showing where is the file:

Comment: my base.scs is there... but even when i try to use the patch... it says that the .scs file is not there...
HELP!!!

Comment: i cant find my scs. base file...[look at the pic. i don't see base](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gsy4W.png)

Comment: It's not in "My documents" folder. It's where you installed your game at first place!